# How do I extract the dictionary from a JSON file to a pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I've extracted the data into a JSON file (it is a nest filed)

I've read_json to extract the data into a pandas:

```
df = pd.read_json('./data0000.json')
```

but got this as the data is nested ( all the fields are under Data):

```
                             Data
0   {field 1, field 2, field 3....)
```

How do I unnest it in a panda dataframe?

Comment: It will help us if you can provide an example of a JSON file you have.

Answer (score 0):

For the following data format, read_json() works as you would like:

```
    [
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
    ]
```

We would still need to see your data for a full fix, but you may also want to explore the "orient" parameter in read_json().

```
    data = pd.read_json('data0000.json',orient='records')
```

Allowed values for orient are: {'split','records','index','columns','values'}

From the docs [link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.read_json.html):

- `DataFrame`

  - default is `'columns'`
  - allowed values are: {'split','records','index','columns','values'}
  - The DataFrame index must be unique for orients 'index' and
    'columns'.
  - The DataFrame columns must be unique for orients 'index',
    'columns', and 'records'.